# websocket connection fails for chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, webpack, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, react-app-rewired

I am upgrading the manifest to v3. When I load the extension I get the following error `WebSocket connection to 'ws://pboiicdpnbleoponcncnednhgapmcbfb/sockjs-node' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` in local development.

This connection is initiated from webpack (more precisely react-app-rewired, seems like they run an own devServer instead of the webpack one).

I don't find anything that helped me with this one yet

Comment: There's no websocket server in an extension. Something in your webpack config is wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: I think it was the react-app-rewired package that some sort of tried to activate this. I removed it and used webpack itself, now this error is gone